# The Meaning of a Complex Energy in Electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, complex-numbers, dielectric, nanoscience

I am currently trying to understand the physics of a fabry-perot resonator with a complex dielectric function. This is in general a standard problem to consider, but including a complex dielectric function leads to some conceptual difficulties.
By just taking the standing waves (indexed by m), we arrive at the following equation to satisfy, after plugging the standing wave solutions into the wave equation;

$$\omega_m= \frac{\pm cm\pi}{a}\left(\frac{1}{n(\omega)+ik(\omega)} \right)$$

where we have used $\sqrt{\epsilon_r(\omega}= n(\omega) + i k(\omega)$ and $n(\omega)$, $k(\omega)$ are the real and imaginary components of the frequency-dependent refractive index. Because the right hand side has a real and imaginary component, the frequencies of the mode should also be a complex quantity. Therefore, we could re-arrange these roots as:

$$\omega_{1,2}=\omega'_{1,2} + i \omega ''_{1,2}=\frac{\pm cm\pi}{a}\left(\frac{1}{n(\omega)+ik(\omega)} \right) $$

These can then be re-arranged to solve for the two complex frequency roots.

\begin{align}
\omega_1 & = \frac{m \pi c}{a (n^2(\omega)+k^2(\omega)} \left[ n(\omega) - i k (\omega) \right] \\
\omega_2 & = \frac{m \pi c}{a (n^2(\omega)+k^2(\omega)} \left[ -n(\omega) + i k (\omega) \right]
\end{align}

Where we can say the first solution takes the positive sign, and the second solution takes the negative sign. Both of these equations are necessarily solved numerically, using some kind of dielectric function. I am particularly interested in using a simple dielectric function of a single lorentzian (single resonance);

$$\epsilon_r=1 + \frac{\omega_p^2}{\omega_o^2-\omega^2 - i \omega \Gamma}$$

where $\omega_p$ is the plasmon frequency, $\omega_o$ is the natural oscillator frequency, $\Gamma$ is the dephasing, and $\omega$ is just the free variable of frequency. At frequencies sufficiently far away from the resonance, n is a constant value and k is zero, so the only interesting things (e.g. multiple sustained frequencies for a given mode index) happen around the resonance within something like twice the dephasing frequency on either side.

My question lies in an interpretation of the complex component of the frequency - in my mind this should estimate the lifetime of a state that would be produced by this kind of analysis. The confusing part though is that the complex part is basically always some very small value. My expectation would be that it would generally be very small except for modes near the resonant frequency, where absorption would rapidly decrease the lifetime, and lead to an increased spectral width of the mode (i.e. larger $\omega''$). Is it wrong to expect this behavior?

Any and all comments would be appreciated - I could not find much discussion on this subject, so the commentary and/or derivation might have serious flaws. The ultimate goal would be to introduce this kind of analysis for a 3-d nanostructure, and find the photon dispersion in the presence of a complex dielectric function, but using a 1-d fabry-perot resonator is already proving difficult.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your notation.  Are $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ just the positive and negative values of $\omega_m$ from your first equation?  If not, what equation are $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ roots of?

Comment: I just edited the question to hopefully better reflect my intent. $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ should be the two values for $\omega_m$, rearranged to a more convenient form. I also fixed what I think was a math error, they are more simple/obvious now.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point of your question, but doesn't your function already have the desired property?  You have $\omega_1 \propto \Im(\epsilon_r^{-1/2})$, and if you try plotting out $\Im(\epsilon_r^{-1/2})$ for some values of $\omega_0$, $\omega_p$, and $\Gamma$, you get something that's highly peaked around $\omega \approx \omega_0$ so long as $\omega _0 \gg \Gamma$.

Comment: > *"The confusing part though is that the complex part is basically always some very small value."* Why do you think so? Near resonance $k(\omega)$ may be large.